# Translating -ish and -aster endings

Tags: vocabulary, etymology, derivation, accidence

There are ways in Latin of expressing less-than-completeness, but I'm intrigued by the strange-ish (!) and allegedly related etymologies given in English dictionaries for these two endings, which are claimed to be derived from Latin and earlier sources.

I recently came upon the phrase 'a goodish way', for which I used the comparative *longius*, in the (alternative) sense of 'rather' or 'somewhat'. Almost immediately afterwards the word 'yellowish' occurred, and for this there is an adjective *fulvaster*. And today I have come upon *novellaster*, 'newish' or 'rather new'.

This has all set me reflecting that *-ish* is a useful modifier for English adjectives, and that in French *-âtre* has a similar use in, for example, *verdâtre*, 'greenish' (though I do not think it so freely used as our English *-ish*). The *-aster* ending is seen in the English 'poetaster' in the same sense while, Chambers' Dictionary attributes the same ending in 'disaster' (via French) to — I quote — [O Fr . . . . from *des* (L *dis-*) with evil sense, and *astre* a star, destiny, from L *astrum*, Gr *astron* star].

Although I've found the above examples, I don't remember any rule for modifying Latin nouns and adjectives in analogous ways — except that, in some cases, the prefix *sub-* can be used as in, for instance, *subruber* and *subraucus*. The whole business seems quite haphazard. It would be very convenient if there were a proper rule: is there any such?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is anything quite like the English -ish in Latin.
The closest thing I know is the diminutive.
Here are some examples of diminutive adjectives where the diminutive means lesser extent instead of smaller size:

- [*acutulus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=acutulus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) from *acutus*
- [*astutulus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dastutulus) from *astutus*
- [*audaculus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Daudaculus) from *audax*
- [*curiosulus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcuriosulus) from *curiosus*
- [*dulciculus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Ddulciculus) from *dulcis*
- [*duriusculus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dduriusculus) from *durus*
- [*eruditulus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Deruditulus) from *eruditus*
- [*fericulus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfericulus) from *ferus*
- [*fessulus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfessulus) from *fessus*
- [*floridulus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfloridulus) from *floridus*
- [*frigidulus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfrigidulus) from *frigidus*

The diminutive is mostly translated as "somewhat" in the linked dictionary entries.

Such adjectives are not very common, but still common enough to see a pattern and feel confident about using the suffix productively.

How to exactly form the diminutive is another question (and worth separate questions), but it is often fairly simple.
I asked about [one aspect of forming diminutives](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2900/79) just a moment ago.

Comment: Let me know if you want more examples. I can extend the list.

Comment: Note that [Priscian considers](https://books.google.com/books?id=5XLSodWAEa8C&pg=PA80&lpg=PA80) -aster to be a diminutive too.

Comment: @brianpck Interesting! That fits pretty well with my answer. That would make the "Latin -ish" more uniformly similar to the familiar diminutive of nouns.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the prefix *sub-*, as you yourself have mentioned, fits the bill quite well. Lewis and Short list *subabsurdus*, *subagrestis*, *subalbus*, *subaccusare*, *subirascor*, etc., to which I could add *subfuscus*, a favorite of Patrick O'Brian.