# Variations on the diminutive: -olus and -ulus

Tags: classical-latin, derivation, spelling, diminutive

The usual Latin diminutive suffix is *-ulus* (or *-ula* or *-ulum*).
However, it sometimes appears as *-olus*, like in *filiolus*, *aculeolus*, *petiolus*, and *bestiola*.
(And perhaps Venezuela, *Venetiola*, is a small Venice.)
**When is *-olus* used instead of *-ulus*?**
It seems that a vowel is followed by *-olus* and a consonant by *-ulus*, but I have not seen this rule explicitly stated.
Does some grammar describe the choice of the diminutive suffix?

Background:
I read recently about a children's parliament (which promotes children's ideas and teaches them the basics of democracy), and I wondered what I would call it in Latin.
I thought a diminutive of *curia* would be a nice translation.
Trying to attach *-ula* to *curia* produced *curiola*, as my intuition immediately rejected *curiula*.
The problem is that I have no idea why I thought so.
Therefore I would like to know how the vowel (o/u) is determined.

Comment: There is also [-culus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-culus#Latin), and -unculus (where _c_ and _unc_ do not add anything, but are consistently used to form diminutives. [This page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-lus#Latin) also says -lus itself is used. Sorry for the lame sources, but I think they might add something to the discussion

Comment: @Rafael I know that *-ulus* is not the only diminutive suffix. I just wanted to focus the question on comparing *-ulus* and *-olus*. I would certainly want to know more about the *-(un)c-* before *-ulus*, but that should go to another question. (Feel free to ask!) I'm not sure I buy the *-lus* suffix, especially if the only example is *porc-ulus*.

Comment: Gobius can be named "Gōbulus" (Name of a gobie native to the Atlantic and Pacific coasts of the Americas), "Gobiusculus", the two-spotted goby. And perhaps, for sure, "Gobiōlus". I think the preference is 'flattering' towards -olus, in words finished in -is/ -es (iolus, eolus), being overwhelming in popular latin

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A word search confirms that ***-olus* is used instead of *-ulus* after a vowel.**

A [Perseus search for words ending in -olus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?lang=la&type=end&page=1&lookup=olus) reveals (among a few false positives, like *malevolus*) that every diminutive form follows a vowel. A similar search for -[vowel]ulus, such as [-iulus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=end&lookup=iulus&lang=la), only returns false positives.

This is confirmed in [Allen and Greenough's Latin Grammar](http://www.hhhh.org/perseant/libellus/aides/allgre/allgre.243.html):

> [Diminutives] are formed by means of the suffixes -
>
> **-ulus (-a, -um), -olus (after a vowel)**, -culus, -ellus, -illus

Answer (score 5):

As brianpck says, after a vowel only *-olus* is possible (and *-ulus* is not).

One other place where *-olus* can appear is after V (consonantal U) or QU, since a general habit in older Latin documents was to write O instead of U (V) after these consonant sounds. (It's not clear whether this O represented the sound /o/, or was just a different spelling of the sound /u/.) E.g. *parvolus* and *servolus* exist as variants of *parvulus* and *servulus,* and the forms *equolam* and *aquolam* can be found in Plautus.

Comment: And the name *Scaevola*, although like with *parvolus* and *servolus* about, it was also written *Scaevula*.