# Constructing Latin diminutives

Tags: new-latin, derivation, suffixes, diminutive

In the course of trying to construct an accurate diminutive form of the word *abdomen* - which for the record is Latin in origin (in the form *abdōmen*), having been borrowed by English via Middle French - for use as the name of a fictional anatomical structure, I've discovered that the Latin language has multiple suffixes for making diminutives. The ones that I've found so far are *-culus*, *-ellus*, *-illus*, *-lus*, *-olus*, *-ullus*, and *-unculus*.

So, what determines which of these suffixes I can/should use for creating a particular diminutive? And what would the correct diminutive of *abdomen* be?

Comment: There are some rules but you won't find them in the old grammars like Allen and Greenbough. Michele Fruyt has written extensively on Latin diminutives.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think *abdomunculum* would be the most regular diminutive of *abdomen.* But it seems a bit difficult to me to give a clear answer because the rules about "proper" diminutive suffixes are often based on the form and gender of the original noun, and I know of no existing diminutives formed on nouns with precisely the same morphological form and gender as *abdomen, abdominis*. If you get it "wrong," you may at least be able to take some comfort from the knowledge that Romans even criticized one another sometimes for using supposedly malformed diminutives.

*Abdomen, abdominis* is a neuter noun of the third declension, of the "consonant stem" sub-declension class, with a stem ending in the consonant "n" specifically. My impression is that any of these features might be relevant to the formation of the diminutive.

### Words with stems ending in *n* often take diminutives in *-cul-*

[brianpck's answer](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/2903/9) to *[Variations on the diminutive: -olus and -ulus](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2900/variations-on-the-diminutive-olus-and-ulus)* contained a link to a page from [Allen and Greenough's Latin Grammar](http://www.hhhh.org/perseant/libellus/aides/allgre/allgre.243.html) that I consulted to try to answer this question. It says

> These diminutive endings are all formed by adding *-lus* to various stems. [...] *-culus* comes from -lus added to adjectives in *-cus* formed from stems in *n-* and *s-*: as, *iuven-cus, Aurun-cus* (cf. *Aurunculeius*), *prís-cus,* whence the *cu* becomes a part of the termination, and the whole ending (*-culus*) is used elsewhere, but mostly with *n-* and *s-* stems, in accordance with its origin.

### Usually, *...in-* + *-cul-* = *...uncul-,* apparently

*[The Formation of Latin
Diminutives of Nouns and Adjectives](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323534846_The_Formation_of_Latin_Diminutives_of_Nouns_and_Adjectives),* compiled by Ian Andreas Miller,  indicates that stems ending *-in-* regularly change the vowel and have *-un-* before *-culus/-culum/-cula.* cnread's answer mentions *homunculus,* from *homo, hominis,* which shows this pattern. There is an interesting note in Miller about the history of this formation saying that the *u* is analogical:

> The *-uncul-* formation in these diminutives was originally created by adding *-culā-, -culo-* to stems in *-on-,* where the *-o-* became *-u-* by phonetic change (cf. *hunc,* earlier *honc*). Some original stems in *-nō-* (*-on-*) later became stems in *-in-* (e.g. *homin-,* earlier *homon-* or *homōn-*) with nominative singular endings in *-ō,* and through the power of analogy the *-uncul-* formation was used with other stems in *-in-* (e.g. *pecten,* stem *pectin-*) and stems in *-n-* with nominative singular forms in *-o* (e.g. *caro,* stem *carn-*) even if they do not actually have stems in *-in-* or *-on-.*

I don't know of any Latin diminutives ending in "...in-cul-" (*vinculum* is derived from the base *vinc-*).

### Gender of diminutives, and the rarity of *-unculum*/*-munculum*

Miller says it is a rule that diminutive nouns derived from third-declension nouns retain the gender of the original noun—which for *abdomen* is neuter—and take the endings *-us, -a* or *-um* according to the usual correspondences between form and gender. So it seems to me that *abdomunculum* would be most regular.

But I'm not entirely certain about recommending *-unculum* rather than *-unculus* as in cnread's answer. There are exceptions to the gender-matching rule; Miller mentions *rana* > *ranunculus.* And since most nouns ending in *-ō* in the nominative are masculine or feminine,  *-unculus* and  *uncula* seem to be much more established in Latin than *-unculum* as suffixes for deriving diminutive nouns from third-declension n-stems. A Perseus search does turn up some existing [nouns ending in *-unculum*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=end&lookup=unculum&lang=la), but none of those results seems to be derived from a third-declension noun with a stem ending in *-in-.*

That said, there are certainly diminutives ending in *-culum* with something else before it; for example, *[corpusculum](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=corpusculum),* from the third-declension neuter noun *corpus.* So perhaps the scarcity of words ending in *-un-culum* specifically is just coincidental.

So far, *[pectunculus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=pectunculus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)* from *pecten* is actually the only example I have seen of a diminutive from a noun ending in *-en, -inis.* It is masculine, but so is the original noun *pecten.*

Most Latin nouns that end in *-en* in the nominative and *-inis* in the genitive seem to have an "m" before this and are neuter. Wiktionary indicates that many of them have a "noun-forming suffix [*-men*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-men#Latin)" and lists a number of them; I searched on Perseus for words starting with the stems up to the "m" of around 10 of them (like "agm," "germ," "carm") but I wasn't able to find any diminutive forms with their own entries. Another neuter third-declension with a consonant other than *m* before *-en,* *-inis* is *gluten.*

I also found a passage in Italian that seems to say that "vimunculum" (which is apparently not attested) would be the expected diminutive form of *vimen*:

> > Dal positivo *vimen* uscirono *viminculus, vinculus, vinclus* (sic). Da quest'ultimo poi abbiamo fatto *vinco* a significare quel frutice lento e pieghevole donde usci il verbo *vincio,* se non anche l'altro *vinco.*
>
> Quasi superfluo il notare che da *vimen* neutro sarebbesi più verisimilmente derivato un neutro, qui poi tanto più certo, in quanto il supposto derivato è realmente *vinculum,* non *vinculus.* Non sarebbe poi gran fatto probabile una tale derivazione da neutri in *-men,* non avendosene alcun esempio; e quando poi si dovesse ammettere, sarebbe stato piuttosto *vimunculum* che *viminculus* (cfr. *pectunculus,* dal masch. *pecten*).

([Archivio Glottologico italiano, Volume 2](https://books.google.com/books?id=VnVIAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA34&lpg=PA34&dq=%22vimunculum%22&source=bl&ots=CwQaDElPDJ&sig=eIgOIFjHpFDCkKJEViBYjX2HDsE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHlpzYgqjWAhUD7YMKHTJ4CKkQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22vimunculum%22&f=false))

I don't speak Italian, but judging from Google translate and cognates, this seems to say that there are no examples of diminutives of neuter nouns in *-men.*

#### Post-classical examples of *-munculum* from *-men* neuters

For what it's worth, I was able to find one example of "germunculum" via Google, in *[Dissertatio inauguralis medica de hominis aetatibus](https://books.google.com/books?id=YrJUAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA41&lpg=PA41&dq=%22germunculum%22&source=bl&ots=wHkWxqdxy7&sig=HzvbYWmIEdfz-UI-gwNf_-TVA9c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiglo2PvqfWAhVH6IMKHVgTDWIQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22germunculum%22&f=false),* 1824:

> En, amicitiae vagabundae in juventute ortum! en, primum pro firmioribus radicibus amoris in alterum sexum figendis **germunculum** primum! (§27, p. 41)

"Stamunculum", from *stamen, staminis,* also seems to have been used, in *[Hortus Malabaricus](https://books.google.com/books?id=xYLOojXB8hgC&pg=PT319&lpg=PT319&dq=%22stamunculum%22&source=bl&ots=M4YnbfIvch&sig=LiCOu8ZEh3XvebJ5R63kW37s7Jk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjM3s_ggajWAhUM54MKHaXBC8MQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22stamunculum%22&f=false).*

So at least some other people also seem to have had the same idea as me about how to form the diminutives of words like this, if necessary.

### Other sources on diminutive formation in Latin

Some other possibly relevant sources I found that I have not yet got a chance to look through:

- *Word Formation in the Roman Sermo Plebeius,* by Frederic Taber Cooper (1895) -- has a section on "Diminutives" starting on [page 164](https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=724PAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&output=reader&hl=en&pg=GBS.PA164)
- Cooper cites some articles by "Paucker," one of which had a title that sounded like it might be helpful: "Deminutive mit d. Suffix -c-ulus, a, um"
  Zeitschr. f. d. oesterr. Gymn. XXVII, p. 273-284. (="Zeitschrift für die österreichischen Gymnasien") I looked though a [Google Books result](https://books.google.com/books?id=cY0NAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA597&lpg=PA597&dq=Paucker%20%22Deminutive%22%20mit%20Suffix%20-c-ulus,%20a,%20um%20%22ZEITSCHRIFT%20f%C3%BCr%20die%20%C3%B6sterreichischen%20GYMNASIEN%22&source=bl&ots=QNovpHHp0X&sig=bxKBq0FqnimxK1ZSAc1QuVpX270&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5i-7rhPXSAhUI1GMKHTH9AIcQ6AEIITAB#v=onepage&q=Paucker%20%22Deminutive%22%20mit%20Suffix%20-c-ulus%2C%20a%2C%20um%20%22ZEITSCHRIFT%20f%C3%BCr%20die%20%C3%B6sterreichischen%20GYMNASIEN%22&f=false) related to this, and found a long list of words with the suffix "-uncul-" that contained many ending in "-uncula" and "-unculus" but none that I could see ending in "-unculum" aside from those already mentioned that are indexed by Perseus and have entries in Lewis & Short.

Comment: So... My first guess of _abdom**i**nculus_ is incorrect?

Comment: @MarqFJA87: I don't know enough to say it is "incorrect," but I haven't found any concrete examples of diminutives ending in "-incul-".

Answer (score 5):

On the model of *homō*, *hominis* (stem = *homin*), the recorded diminutives of which are *homullus* (< *homōnlus*) and *homunculus*, I'd guess *abdōmullus* or *abdōmunculus* (update: or maybe *abdōmullum* or *abdōmunculum*).

The topic of suffixes for various types of words is covered in, e.g., §176 ff. of Gildersleeve & Lodge, *Latin Grammar*. Diminutive suffixes are covered in §181.12. As the example of *homō* shows, there are sometimes multiple possibilities.

Comment: Searching Perseus, I didn't find any other diminutives ending in "-mullus," but I did find a couple others ending in "[-munculus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=end&lookup=munculus&lang=la)": *pulmunculus* and *sermunculus.* Both end in -mo rather than -men in the nominative, though, so they aren't perfectly analogous to "abdomen" (I don't know if that's relevant though).

Comment: I just thought of something: wouldn't a diminutive of "abdomen" be expected to be neuter, since "abdomen" is a neuter word?

Comment: @sumelic Not always - e.g., *puella* is a diminutive of *puer* - but here I think it'd be better.

Comment: @Anonym, I'd say the proper diminutive of *puer* is *puellus*, from which *puella* is derived.

Comment: @TKR You are correct, and note that there's also [*puera*](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=puera). (Edited: [Lewis & Short definition](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=puera&la=la#lexicon))