# I can't find via Google "Flumen" diminutives

Tags: romance-languages, diminutive

I have difficulties finding this word' possible diminutives.. this substantive  ending in most declesions problematic **-en**.

I answer Google: Google does not give me hypotetic resultates.

Comment: "flumunculum, i, n." if we are to follow the example "pecten,tinis,m." mentioned in [The_Formation_of_Latin_Diminutives_of_Nouns_and_Adjectives](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323534846_The_Formation_of_Latin_Diminutives_of_Nouns_and_Adjectives) , methinks.

Comment: Apart from what Jacqueline says, [flumicellum](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dflumicellum) apparently has one or two late Latin attestations.

Comment: Related: https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2967/constructing-latin-diminutives