# What is the etymology of the suffix -aster, -astri?

Tags: greek, etymology, suffixes

It's been a bit difficult for me to find good information about the etymology of the derivational suffix *-aster.* De Vaan doesn't seem to talk about it. A number of sources indicate that it is from Greek; e.g. [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-aster#Etymology_2) says

> From suffix originally forming Ancient Greek nouns from verbs ending in -άζειν (-ázein).

and says that *-astrum* is an alternative form, which seems to imply that it would go back to a Greek ending *-αστρον* or *-αστρος.*

But it's been hard for me to find information about the use of *-αστρον* in Greek. Searching Perseus only turned up [20 examples of words ending in *-αστρον*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=end&lookup=astron&lang=greek), and most of them don't look very similar in meaning to Latin forms suffixed with *-aster.* The only one that looks close to me is *[λαίμαστρον](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dlai%2Fmastron),* which LSJ defines as "greedy beast', term of abuse": it seems to be derived from a verb *λαιμάσσω.* The results for [*-αστρος*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=end&lookup=astros&lang=greek) don't look much better: 14 nouns, of which 5 seem to be derived from *ἄστρον* "star" and 4 seem to be derived from *γαστήρ* "belly". I also looked at words ending in [*-αστήρ*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=end&lookup=asthr&lang=greek) (which I'm not sure is even very plausible as a candidate source of the Latin second-declension form *-aster*) and they mostly don't look too similar to Latin *-aster* words either.

What is the exact hypothesis about how Latin is supposed to have developed a  suffix *-aster* based on some Greek ending? Or if there are other hypotheses that are currently considered plausible, please tell me about them.

I am aware of one alternative proposal (at least for the word *patraster*) that was criticized by Fr. Stolz in 1905: H. Ehrlich apparently tried to derive *patraster* (which he apparently supposed to have a long vowel in the penult:  *patrāster*) from *patrāvester,* but Stolz argues that the change āvĕ > ā is implausible in this context ("Über Angeblichen Wandel Von Lat. āvĕ Zu ā." Zeitschrift für Vergleichende Sprachforschung auf dem Gebiete der Indogermanischen Sprachen 38, no. 3).

---

Here are examples of the three main usages that I know of for this suffix.

- *-aster, -astra, -astrum* is found at the end of some adjectives with the sense "somewhat", such as *[surdaster](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dsurdaster)* "somewhat deaf" from *surdus.* I've seen it called a diminutive suffix in this context (see e.g. this question, the answer and comments: [Translating -ish and -aster endings](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2885/translating-ish-and-aster-endings)).
- It also appeared in the kinship terms *[patraster](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpatraster)* and *[filiaster](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfiliaster).* The meaning seems to be not entirely straightforward to translate into English, but it appears that these words could refer to either what in English would be called "in-law" relationships or what in English would be called "step" relationships. Wiktionary says that in Italian, "[fratellastro](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fratellastro#Italian)" can mean "half brother". I suppose that in theory, these words could have a different origin, but the meaning does seem relatively similar (a "patraster" is somewhat like a "pater", but somewhat different).
- It appeared in some pejorative derived nouns like *[philosophaster](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=philosophaster)* "a bad philosopher".

Answer (score 3):

I found the following brief footnote on two suggested etymologies for *-aster* in *The Alphabet of Galen: Pharmacy from Antiquity to the Middle Ages,* A Critical Edition of the Latin Text with English Translation and Commentary by Nicholas Everett, which says that "there are different theories on [the suffix's] linguistic origins":

> Seck and Schnorr von Carolsfeld 1884 suggested adaptation from substantives in *-os* + *tro* (e.g. *flustrum,* from *flovostrom*) to other nominal stems; Lindsay and Stolz saw it as an extension of the comparative *-tero-,* derived from *-atus* formations: Bolling 1897 suggested that the botanical terms derived from the qualifying adjectives *sylvestris* and *agrestris*.

([p. 97](https://books.google.com/books?id=R2DXb3tF7zwC&pg=PA97))

Answer (score 2):

I am non-expert, but you are almost certainly mis-parsing the ending.

Take the standard  word for "hook", [ἄγκιστρον](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E1%BC%84%CE%B3%CE%BA%CE%B9%CF%83%CF%84%CF%81%CE%BF%CE%BD), so the Greek ending is [-τρον](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-%CF%84%CF%81%CE%BF%CE%BD#Ancient_Greek), from IE [-trom](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/-trom), for insturment.

So they (IEs) all had it, including the Latin -trum.

The ***ασ***(-τρον) you hook on comes from the stem, which might often be a verb such as -άζειν, etc....

Comment: Thanks. The instrument suffix seems like a reasonable source for the -ter/-tr- part (the Everett quote in my answer says Seck and Schnorr von Carolsfeld 1884 identified that suffix as the source), but I'm still confused about how it got -as- before it. Are there any good examples of Greek words ending in -αστρον from verbs in -άζειν?

Comment: I agree with you, that the -ας- part comes from verbs in -άζω, but I cannot figure how a diminutive/pejorative meaning could evolve from the -τρον whih means _tool, instrument._

Comment: @Dario No, the pejorative twist is just a connotation.  λαιμ-άσσω is being greedy, and λαίμαστρον is the "agent of greed". The ending itself is not associated with pejorative functions.  Think of "he is an eating machine" in English.

Comment: @sumelic:   σκεπ-άζω > σκέπαστρον  to cover> covering .